# Using regex in Python 2.7.3 to search text and output matches

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I am trying to accomplish exactly what the title says. The program is meant to read a .txt file from a specified path and match the terms specified in the code. This is what I have so far:

```
import re

source = open("C:\\test.txt", "r")
lines = []

for line in source:
    line = line.strip()
    lines.append(line)
    if re.search('reply', line):
        print 'found: ', line
```

As you can see, I am specifying the term 'reply' using re.search but this restricts me to one term. I know there is a way to specify a list or dictionary of words to search for, but my attempts have failed. I think it's possible to create a list with something like ...

```
keywords = ['reply', 'error', 'what']
```

... but despite what I've read on this site, I can't seem to incorporate this into the code properly. Any advice or assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

PS. If I wanted to make the search case sensitive, would I be able to use ...

```
"(.*)(R|r)eply(.*)"
```

... in the list of terms I want to find?

Comment: For the PS, I'm assuming you mean make it NOT case sensitive (case insensitive). If so, an easier way is str.lower().

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
import re
source = open("input", "r")
lines = []
keywords = ['reply', 'error', 'what']
# join list with OR, '|', operators
# re.I makes it case-insensitive
exp = re.compile("|".join(keywords), re.I)
for line in source:
    line = line.strip()
    lines.append(line)
    if re.search(exp, line):
        print 'found: ', line
```

Comment: Thank you! Learned a lot from this one :)

Answer (score 1):

With re.search(), you pass a single string, but you can specify quite complex patterns.  See the docs on the [Python re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), which has a section on "Regular Expression Syntax".

In fact you have the answer in your question... `"R|r"` searches for "R" or "r", so `"reply|error|what"` searches for 'reply', 'error', or 'what'.

> PS. If I wanted to make the search case sensitive, would I be able to use ...
>   "`(.*)(R|r)eply(.*)`"

There's no need for the `.*` bit (and it may make your code slower).  The re.search() function looks for a match *anywhere* in the string.  `(R|r)eply` will look for 'reply' or 'Reply', it won't match 'REPLY' or 'rePly'.

If you want a case insensitive search, there's a `flags=re.IGNORECASE` option that you can pass to `re.search()`.  E.g.:

```
re.search('reply', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Adding a comment to the .py file about this!